# CSS Transition Delay on Value Change

Tags: css, transactions, delay

Riddle me this:

I have an empty SPAN value waiting for a validation "confirmed" text string. The text string needs to automagically fade away after a second or two (without user interaction). How can this be done with pure CSS?

Since there is no user initiated trigger like :hover, would it be best to set a rule based on the exact text string value? Seems inflexible. How do you set when the second or two delay starts?

This does not seam to work...

```
<span class="validationTextString" value=""></span>

.validationTextString[value=""]
{opacity: 1.0;
transition: opacity 0.3s linear 2s;}

.validationTextString[value="confirmed"]
{opacity: 0.0;}
```

Thanks for your help.

--UPDATE--

The above rule actually DOES work. But only ONCE - since the value doesn't change after it is populated. Is there a generic CSS value to trigger on change rather than a specific value? Or a way to reset the rule after triggered?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt seem to me that this is possible with pure CSS. this is because the css is only called at load time, so it has no way to check if the value is now 'confirmed'. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjuM8/), the text box containing 'confirmed' at load time disappears, but the other does not, even if you do type 'confirmed'.

also, you need '$' signs like this:

```
.validationTextString[value$=""]
{opacity: 1.0;
transition: opacity 0.3s linear 2s;}
```

unfortunately, it also does not work when using `:hover` or `:active` like this:

```
.validationTextString:hover[value$=""]
    {opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear 2s;}
```

again a box containing 'confirmed' at load will disapper on hover, but blank boxes with 'confirmed' inputted still do not disappear.